Customize editor_advanced_link module
I have installed the editor_advanced_link module with Drupal 10. Is there a way to always enable "Open in new window" by default? It should then look like this when the window opens:

To solve the problem I wrote a module with the following code: Following these instructions
function vwp_ckeditor5_link_ckeditor5_plugin_info_alter(array &$plugin_definitions): void {
  if (isset($plugin_definitions['ckeditor5_link'])) {
    if ($plugin_definitions['ckeditor5_link'] instanceof CKEditor5PluginDefinition) {
      $link_plugin_definition = $plugin_definitions['ckeditor5_link']->toArray();

      $link_plugin_definition['ckeditor5']['config']['link']['decorators'][] = [
        'mode' => 'manual',
        'label' => t('Open in new window'),
        'defaultValue' => TRUE,
        'attributes' => [
          'target' => '_blank',
        ],
      ];

      $plugin_definitions['ckeditor5_link'] = new KEditor5PluginDefinition($link_plugin_definition);
    }
  }
}

Now I highlight the element twice but the property of the original element is not changed. See here:


Yes because [] means you are adding a new element instead of editing the existing element.

Is there a way to set the button of the editor-advanced-link module to 'defaultValue' => TRUE
